# Usage of Verb て-form あります

Tags: grammar, aspect

```
Q: かばんはかいましたか。

A: 1.　はい、もうかいました。  
 　2.　はい、もうかってあります。
```

Both answers also correct, but when should I use the second answer?

Comment: I think you can say that the te form you quote is used with auxiliary verbs. The meaning depends entirely on the auxiliary verbs in question.

There are many auxiliaries. You mention いる、しまう、ある、おく. Others are みる、いく、くる.

Comment: 「～て」+「いる、しまう、ある、…」の「いる、しまう、ある、…」って、助動詞じゃなくて補助動詞ですよね。補助動詞って、subsidiary verb ではなく auxiliary verb とも訳されるんでしょうか。

Comment: I've reopened the question because the asker has edited it to be more specific.

Comment: You might want to wait to accept an answer.  Someone might write a better one.

Comment: Now I think it's a duplicate of [this](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14760/9749) but I can't vote to close again...

Answer (score 0):

1. かいました　I bought
2. もうかってあります I have bought

First is past tense. Second is present perfect tense. You would use the present perfect tense if you want to stress in the present time.