# What does 入ってなかった mean?

Tags: meaning, verbs

I couldn't understand 入って**なかった**, what verb is it after 入って?

> で、帰ったときに携帯はかばんに**入ってなかった**だろう？

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「入{はい}ってなかった」＝「入って**い**なかった」

In informal speech, that 「い」 is very often omitted.

That is 「入る + いる + ない」 in the past tense ***state***, not ***action***.

> "And then, when you returned home, your cellphone was not in your bag, right?"

Answer (score 1):

入ってなかった is the negative past form of 入ってある. The -てある form is used to indicate that "something has been done to something and the resultant state remains" (from Makino Dictionary of Japanese Grammar). The translation of your sentence would be:

> So, when you came back the phone was missing from your bag, right? (implying that someone took it)

Here's an example to understand the difference between -てある and -ている:

窓が開いている -> The window is open. (no agent or reason implied)

窓が開けてある -> The window is open (because someone opened it).

Check [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5505/17797) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14760/17797) question to learn more about -てある and -ている.