# When using 比べる, should I use を or が for the object being compared?

Tags: particles, particle-が, particle-を

I have seen sentences 1 and 4, but are sentences 2 and 3 grammatical?

My question is regarding the use of を/が with the object being compared, in sentences with 比べる.

> 1. 植物の世界にも（今年**を**）去年**と比べて**著しく相違が見えた。
> 2. 植物の世界にも（今年**が**）去年**と比べて**著しく相違が見えた。
> 3. 花をつけた蓮**に比べて**白鷺**を**大変小さいように描いてある。
> 4. 花をつけた蓮**に比べて**白鷺**が**大変小さいように描いてある。

Sources for sentences 1 and 4: 寺田寅彦「あひると猿」(sentence 1) and 宮本百合子「蓮花図」(sentence 4): https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/8897154.html

Comment: `植物の世界にも（今年を）去年と比べて著しく相違が見えた。` -- Does the original sentence really say 今年**を** ? I'd say 「植物の世界にも今年**は**去年と比べて著しく相違が見えた。」or「今年**は**植物の世界にも去年と比べて著しく相違が見えた。」

Comment: Hm, the sources are 寺田寅彦「あひると猿」(sentence 1) and 宮本百合子「蓮花図」(sentence 4): https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/8897154.html

Comment: そのページには `（今年を）去年と：「植物の世界にも去年と比べて著しく相違が見えた。」` とありますので、原文は「植物の世界にも去年と比べて著しく相違が見えた。」であって、「植物の世界にも今年を去年と比べて著しく相違が見えた。」ではありませんね。そのページで書かれた「今年を」は、「去年と」で「何**を**去年と比べているか」を説明したものですね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. 植物の世界にも（今年**を**）去年と比べて著しく相違が見えた。
> 2. 植物の世界にも（今年**が**）去年と比べて著しく相違が見えた。

Both sound unnatural to me. I would rather say:

植物の世界にも今年**は**去年と比べて著しく相違が見えた。 or
今年**は**植物の世界にも去年と比べて著しく相違が見えた。

(with 今年は modifying the main clause 相違が見えた)

because you say...

今年**は**植物の世界にも著しく相違が見えた。 or
植物の世界にも今年**は**著しく相違が見えた。

... with or without 「去年と比べて」.

To use 今年**を**, I'd say...

植物の世界にも、今年**を**去年と比べ**ると**著しく相違が見えた。 or
植物の世界にも、今年**と**去年**を**比べ**ると**著しく相違が見えた。

(...with 今年を / 今年と modifying the sub-clause 比べる.)

---

> 3. 花をつけた蓮に比べて白鷺**を**大変小さいように描いてある。
> 4. 花をつけた蓮に比べて白鷺**が**大変小さいように描いてある。

I think both are fine, because you can say either...

白鷺**を**大変小さいように描いてある。 or
白鷺**が**大変小さいように描いてある。

... with or without 「花をつけた蓮に比べて」.

Sentence 4 sounds a bit more natural to me, because I think it's more natural to interpret 白鷺 as the subject of 大変小さい rather than 描いてある.

<sub>As a side note,「が+transitive verb+てある」 and 「を+transitive verb+てある」 are both correct. Please see [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/53313/9831) if you're interested.</sub>

---

例えば・・・

> 日本**は**、アメリカに比べて面積が小さい。

という文では、日本**を**アメリカと比べています。でも、「日本**を**アメリカに比べて面積が小さい。」とは言わないでしょう。<sub>「日本**を**アメリカに比べると、日本**は**面積が小さい。」「日本**と**アメリカ**を**比べると、日本のほう**が**面積が小さい。」なら言えそうですが、回りくどいですね。</sub>

Comment: Apologies for not adding the sources earlier, but I found sentences 1 and 4 in the sources above. Perhaps in their contexts they would be natural?

Comment: According to the page you linked to, the original sentence is 「植物の世界にも去年と比べて著しく相違が見えた。」, not 「植物の世界にも**今年を**去年と比べて著しく相違が見えた。」. In the 「（今年を）去年と」 part, they're trying to show what's being compared with 去年.

Answer (score 2):

<del>1. 植物の世界にも（今年を）去年と比べて著しく相違が見えた。

・ I don't think the sentence of 1 is natural, but it could be natural.

・ Basically there is a lack of the object to be depicted by "著しく相違が見えた" in 1. If I add some words to 1 to make it natural, it will be like:

(A) 植物の世界にも（今年を）去年と比べて著しく相違が**生じているように思わせる兆候**が見えた。

(B) 植物の世界にも（今年を）去年と比べて**外来種の花の生育に（おいて）** 著しく相違が見えた。</del>

<del>2. 植物の世界にも（今年が）去年と比べて著しく相違が見えた。

・ I don't think the sentence of 2 is natural, and it couldn't be natural because of が.</del>

3. 花をつけた蓮に比べて白鷺を大変小さいように描いてある。
   ・ grammatical
   ・ 白鷺を小さいように描いてある is not natural, I like it to be written like 白鷺を大変小さく描いてある, 白鷺を大変小さくなるように描いてある or 白鷺を大変小さく見えるように描いてある.
4. 花をつけた蓮に比べて白鷺が大変小さいように描いてある。
   ・ grammatical
   ・ 白鷺が小さいように描いてある is not natural, I like it to be written like 白鷺が大変小さく描いてある, 白鷺が大変小さくなるように描いてある or 白鷺が大変小さく見えるように描いてある.

The difference of nuance between 3 and 4 is, I think, on what the writer places the point more; the point is placed on the drawer/painter in 3 while 白鷺 in 4.

If I make the difference more clear they will be like:
3'. 花をつけた蓮に比べて**画家は**白鷺を大変小さく見えるように描いてある。
4'. 花をつけた蓮に比べて**画面の中で**白鷺が大変小さく見えるように描いてある。

---

## EDIT

> 1. 植物の世界にも（今年を）去年と比べて著しく相違が見えた。

出典が寺田寅彦と追加情報がありましたが、それでも、寺田寅彦氏にしては悪文だなと思っておりました。そして、「今年を」が何故括弧の中に入っているのかが不思議でした。原典の「[あひると猿](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=bxLGkcF4qrgC&pg=PP6&lpg=PP6&dq=%E6%A4%8D%E7%89%A9%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82%EF%BC%88%E4%BB%8A%E5%B9%B4%E3%82%92%EF%BC%89%E5%8E%BB%E5%B9%B4%E3%81%A8%E6%AF%94%E3%81%B9%E3%81%A6%E8%91%97%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E7%9B%B8%E9%81%95%E3%81%8C%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%88%E3%81%9F%E3%80%82&source=bl&ots=W8CGOF25B1&sig=d1tyme2MdFVZBYBKoZGGkBKiC_Y&hl=ja&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB8pv5rs_WAhUDE7wKHSzyD0UQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%E6%A4%8D%E7%89%A9%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82%EF%BC%88%E4%BB%8A%E5%B9%B4%E3%82%92%EF%BC%89%E5%8E%BB%E5%B9%B4%E3%81%A8%E6%AF%94%E3%81%B9%E3%81%A6%E8%91%97%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E7%9B%B8%E9%81%95%E3%81%8C%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%88%E3%81%9F%E3%80%82&f=false)」を見て納得しました。質問者が原文からの引用を間違っていたのでは何ともしようがありませんね。

寺田寅彦との追加情報がある前、「植物の世界にも」とありましたので、「動物の世界」の話が詳しくあり、その続きにこの文があるのかなと思いましたがそのとおりでした。

「動物の世界では、今年は昨年と比べて色々な事象で相違が観測できた。植物の世界に目を転じてみて**も**、多くの点で相違が見えた。」が寺田氏の文章の流れです。相違は「今年」と「去年」という時ではなく、それぞれの年の中で生じている、あるいは観察できる**動植物の事象**です。「今年の動植物の事象を昨年の同じ動植物の事象と比べると著しく相違がある」です。

３、４に関しては、４は宮本百合子「蓮花図」からの引用と追加情報がありましたが、３と４のいずれが日本語として自然かとか文法的にどうかではなく、私の最初の判断と同じで、白鷺をどう見たかによって自ずといずれかの表現になります。
４の文章を書いた宮本百合子さんは「白鷺」に着目しています。一方、「白鷺」が描かれたキャンバスに「白鷺」を含めた絵を描いた画家がこのキャンバスの中で白鷺をどう描こうとしたのかという画家の意図に作者が着目した場合は３の文章でなくては表現できません。
試しに４を「花をつけた蓮に比べて白鷺が大変小さいように描かれてある。」と受身形にしてもあまり意味が変わりませんが、３ではニュアンスを含めた意味を変えずに受身形にできません。暗に存在する画家を受身形で処理できないからです。

従って、４は絵そのものに着目がありますので静的ですが、３は画家の意図が文として暗に表現されていますので、動きのある文章として伝わります。違いを感じてください。

Comment: Apologies for not adding the sources earlier, but I found sentences 1 and 4 in the sources above. Perhaps in their respective contexts they would be natural?

Comment: "動物の世界では、**今年は昨年と比べて**色々な事象で相違が観測できた。植物の世界に目を転じてみても…" ←　やっぱり「今年を」ではなく「今年**は** 」を使いたくなりますよね？

Comment: @Chocolateさん：余り意識していませんでしたが「今年は」でしたね。たぶん「今年」を第三者的に観測すると「今年を」でしょう。「今年」にどぷっり嵌まって肌で感じているときは「今年は」ですね。それにしても、質問者の（１）には考え込んでしまいました。括弧なしの **今年を** がしかも寺田寅彦さんと知っていたらどう感じたか恐ろしい限りです。ところで、３、４の私の感じ方はどうでしょうか。