# Understanding 他動詞vs自動詞 more clearly

Tags: grammar, transitivity

I have been trying to grasp the concepts of transitive vs intransitive as I learn Japanese and had some questions on the following

窓を開けている... OK
窓を開けてある..... OK
窓が開いている.... OK
now I have an issue with the following sentence

窓が開けてある.... X?

does 窓が開けてある, make sense? I thought it would be wrong since we cannot use が with 自動詞. In my book under the transitive verb portion is says that

> object set by the particle を

Thus should the grammatical sentence be 窓を開けてある？

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5505/stative-verbs-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b-vs-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%a6%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b-vs-%ef%bd%9e-%e3%82%89-%e3%82%8c%e3%82%8b

Comment: @YuuichiTam Thanks man. I was reading https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13158322958, and it seems different people are saying different things so I am having a hard time grasping this... so are all sentences that I wrote OK?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that at the basic level only transitive verbs (and some intransitive exceptions) should be used with the particle を to mark their objects. However, this changes the moment things verbs are conjugated into other forms. てある is a *stative verb*. Once ～てある is added to the end of a verb, it loses transitivity.

So although you would use を in this sentence:

> 誰が窓を開けた。
> Someone opened the window.

You would not use を in the following sentences:

> 誰かに窓が開けてある。
> The window was opened by someone (for a certain purpose).

> 窓が誰かに開けられた。
> The window was opened by someone。

So, in cases like ～てある and the passive form (開けられる), transitive verbs no longer use the particle を. Once verbs are conjugated into other forms, the way they are used often changes. As a result, 「窓を開けてある」would not be correct in most contexts.

There are exceptions where ～てある is used with the particle を to emphasize the volition of the agent, but it is not regarded as grammatically correct by most. Oftentimes, を is also replaced by は in those circumstances.

Comment: Not to mention there are still some Intransitive verbs that use を right out the box, such as 出る. As in, 場所を出る

Comment: Hi @Shurim, do you mean then using を is incorrect here? When I asked my Japanese friend he said 窓を開けてある makes sense to him although he feels it sounds a bit weird.

Comment: @Lucas, yes my book listed when you are leaving or entering a location as an exception

Comment: @bob As Yuuichi says in his answer, を sounds a bit awkward with ～てある. It does exist, but is rather rare.

Answer (score 1):

が ～ + a transitive verb + てある and が ～ an intransitive + ている mean "the state of the result". So 窓が開けてある and 窓が開いている are natural.

窓を開けている is the progressive form of 窓を開ける or someone keeps the window open intentionally.

I think 窓を開けてある is a bit unnatural and isn't often used.

Source:https://www.tomojuku.com/blog/teoku/tearu1/
http://www.coelang.tufs.ac.jp/mt/ja/gmod/contents/explanation/046.html