# Question on expressing a half-completed action -- 動作が中途である状態

Tags: grammar

> 手紙を書きかけたんですが、まだ書いていません。
>
> I got started on the letter, but I haven't finished writing it yet.

The ending かける indicates that an action has been started but has not been brought to a finish or an end. However in this example I am puzzled by the second half of the sentence.

If I break it down literally, this is the way I comprehend it:

手紙を書きかけたんですが、I started (but did not finish the letter), but...

まだ書いていません。 still am not writing (the letter).

Assuming the highlighted translation is correct, what am I misreading in the second half of the sentence? I am puzzled by the use of the negative in the second half, as I would have assumed まだ書いています would make more sense to correspond with the desired meaning of the translation. I guess in this example using 書いています would have expressed a completed action, so 書いていません means "not finished writing" rather than "not writing"?

Let me try making another example:

> ごはんを作りかけたんですが、まだ作っていません。
>
> I started to make food, but I still haven't finished yet.

Compare the latter example to this:

> A 　ごはん作った？
>
> B 　まだ作っていません。
>
> A 　Did you make food?
>
> B　Not yet.
>
> (perhaps implying that food preparation has not yet started?)

If one writes the original sentence in the positive how does the meaning change?
Would the following translation be correct?

> 手紙を書きかけたんですが、まだ書いています。
>
> I got started on the letter, but I'm still writing it.

Comment: まだ書いていません (I have not finished writing yet) is fine here, but I am not sure how to explain this….  まだ書いています (I am still writing) is also fine and has almost the same meaning (with a different focus).  So if someone asks whether this person has finished writing, both まだ書いています and まだ書いていません mean almost the same thing.  Interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at

[When is Vている the continuation of action and when is it the continuation of state?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/when-is-v%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B-the-continuation-of-action-and-when-is-it-the-continuation-of-state/3140#3140)

To summarize quickly, Japanese has "action verbs", for which ている expresses progressiveness

> 食べている is eating

and "change-of-state verbs" for which ている expresses completeness

> 落ちている has fallen (or maybe "is lying on the floor")

but the separation of verbs is not clear-cut. It highly depends on context, and also speaker preference, to some degree, it seems. See [Does Vて+いる always mean an action already completed?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3262) for more discussion.

So in 書いている meaning "is writing", 書く is acting as an action verb, and when meaning "has written", it is acting as a change-of-state verb.

For what it's worth, the use of the ている form to indicate completion for action verbs is [commonly discussed](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=4601), but it seems to be a common observation that it's more common in the negative than the positive, i.e.

> 書いている  most likely to mean "is writing", but might mean "has written"
>   書いていない ambiguous between "is not writing" and "has not written"

Comment: Thank you. I was using "Japanese verbs at a glance" by Naoko Chino, which sometimes has quirky or unwieldy examples, it seems.

Comment: I agree that 書き終えていません is probably prescriptively more correct, but I do not think that there is anything wrong or ambiguous about saying まだ書いていません in OP’s example.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto I agree that using ている as perfective aspect for action verbs is very common and correct in speech. And it might well be in (formal) writing as well, so maybe I shouldn't have added the last paragraph. There is definitely something fishy going on with the combination of tense-aspect and negative, too. The negative of 書いた is generally 書かなかった, but the negative of もう書いた is not まだ書かなかった, but rather まだ書いていない (or まだ書き終えていない).

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto, the example has context, so it's unambiguous, you're right. But 書いていない in isolation is ambiguous between "is not writing" and "has not written".

Comment: Well, I know that 書いていない in isolation can mean both “is not writing” and “has not written,” but I do not think that textbooks are expected to use sentences whose individual parts would be unambiguous even when used in isolation.  The sentence “手紙を書きかけたんですが、まだ書いていません” as a whole sounds perfectly fine for me, and I find nothing wrong with including this sentence in textbooks.

Comment: If it is grammatical and intelligible, how would you interpret the sentence without the まだ ?
手紙を書きかけたんですが、書いていません。
Could this sentence exist?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto, you are right. My last paragraph probably mostly reflected my prejudices about Japanese textbooks, and didn't add much value. Replaced it with something that more or less matches my intuition.