# Function of 「masu-stem」＋よる in Kansai-ben

Tags: grammar, dialects, kansai-ben, aspect

Several years ago an acquaintance introduced me to the Hiroshima dialect and mentioned clear distinction between perfect and continuous aspects:

Example 1:

> The bus is coming.
>   Standard:　バスが来ている。
>   Chugoku:　バスが来よる。
>
> The bus has already arrived.
>   Standard:　バスが来ている。 -- same as above
>   Chugoku:　バスが来とる。

Example 2:

> When I got up this morning and opened the window, it was raining.
>   (still raining)
>  Standard:　今朝起きて窓を開けたら、雨が降っていた。
>   Chugoku:　今朝起きて窓を開けたら、雨が降りよった。
>
> When I got up this morning and opened
>   the window, I found it had rained. (already stopped.)
>   Standard:　今朝起きて窓を開けたら、雨が降っていた。
>  Chugoku:　今朝起きて窓を開けたら、雨が降っとった。

Now living in Kansai, I hear verbs like 言いよる, 来よった, 当てよった quite often, but so far assumed it was regional variation of past tense: 言っている, 来た, 当てた.

Now that I looked at the explanation of Hiroshima-ben, I started to wonder if  this tense distinction was present in Kansai area too?

Is it archaic and getting extinct now because of hyōjungo prevalence?

Or maybe 「masu-stem」＋よる does have different function in Kansai-ben?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the English _the bus is coming_ really continuous?

Comment: English *The bus is coming* is certainly progressive, though a habitual/iterative interpretation is possible, but it's never perfective like Japanese バスが来ている.

Comment: バスが来ている means 'The bus is here', not 'The bus is coming'; for that, you want バスが来る.

Comment: @snailboat, I think _The bus is coming_ means もうすぐバスが来る. I can't imagine using the progressive to express this idea in Chinese or Japanese.

Comment: @Nothingatall, the situation is not so simple, have a look at http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3262/does-v%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b-always-mean-an-action-already-completed

Comment: @Nothing at all : The *bus* is here would have a past tense for 来る as it has already done the coming バスが来た. 来ている could go either way (is in the process of coming / is in the state of having come already).

Comment: @Yang Muye Adding the もうすぐ initially would add soon to the English meaning. The bus in coming soon > もうすぐバスが来る. The bus is coming would just be バスが来る or under certain conditions バスが来ている (if referring to the state of the buses coming).

Comment: It would be of note that ～とる also has use in 博多弁（福岡）and 北九州弁（福岡）

Answer (score 5):

As you noticed, the auxiliary verb [よる](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%88%E3%82%8B-406886), used in the form of "連用形＋よる", mainly in the western part of Japan, has two different functions.

One is よる used to form the progressive form, which corresponds to ～ている in 標準語:

> - 「今、なにしよるん?」「勉強しよるんじゃ。」 (広島弁)
>     ≒ 「今、なんしょーん?」「勉強しょんじゃ。」 (contracted 広島弁)
>     ≒ 「今、何しているの?」「勉強しているんだ。」 (標準語)
>     ≒ "What are you doing now?" "I'm studying."

Another usage of よる is related to accusation, surprise, or just plain emphasis. This is partly similar to [～やがる](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/221163/m0u/) used also in slangy 標準語.

> - うわ、ほんまに来よった!  (大阪弁)
>     ≒ うわ、本当に来やがった! (標準語)
>     ≒ [accusingly/surprisingly] Wow, (you/he/they) *did* come! (although it was not expected)
> - 宝くじが当たりよった! (大阪弁)
>     ≒ 宝くじが当たった! (標準語)
>     ≒ I won a lottery! (not "I was winning ...")

I believe this kind of よる is not related to tense in any way.

Another example:

> - あいつ、嘘を言いよった。(mainly 大阪弁)
>     ≒ [accusingly] He told a lie!
> - それ、ママがいつも言いよった。(mainly 中国四国方言)
>     ≒ My mom was always saying that. (past progressive)

(**EDIT as per the comments below:** The 'progressive' usage of よる may be specific to 中国四国方言 including 広島弁, and I am better at it than 大阪弁. See this [Wikipedia discussion](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80#.E6.96.87.E6.B3.95). I removed the word 関西弁 because it is ambiguous and [may or may not include 中国方言](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%96%A2%E8%A5%BF%E5%BC%81).)

I'm afraid I don't know whether 大阪弁 actually distinguishes between the perfect tense and the past tense in some way.

Comment: My mom was always saying that. (past progressive) >> We say more like 「ママがいつも言うとった」 or「ママがいつも言うたはった」

Comment: @Shoko うーん、中四国方言と大阪弁の違いじゃないですかね。少なくとも阿波弁だと過去の習慣を指して「よう言いよったわ」「ようやんりょったんじょ」と言います。

Comment: あら、その例文、大阪弁(関西弁)の例文かと・・・。Is 「それ、ママがいつも言いよった」 an example sentence of 中国四国弁?

Comment: たった今、私たち二人とも、同時にダウンボートされましたね・・・edit: 質問も同時に-1されたようですね・・・

Comment: あんまり厳密に大阪というより、大雑把に西日本…みたいな書き方のつもりでしたが、直しておきます。「ちっちゃい頃、ようこの道を歩っきょったわ」「昔は踊んりょったんじゃが…」というのは、瀬戸内辺りだと普通だと思うのですが、きっと「大阪弁」ではないですよねえ。

Answer (score 4):

In Kansai-ben (or, in Kyoto and Osaka), we say:

〖する〗(do / will do):
「する、言う、くる」 <-- 「する、いう、くる」
「しよる、いいよる、きよる*」　<-- 「する、いう、くる」 **+おる/よる**
「しはる、いわはる、きはる」  <-- 「する、いう、くる」 **+はる**
(*also pronounced しおる、いいおる、きおる)

〖している〗(is doing / have done):
「してる、言うてる、きてる」 <-- 「している、いっている、きている」
「しとる、いうとる、きとる*」　<-- 「している、いっている、きている」 **+おる/よる**
「したはる、いうたはる、きたはる」　<-- 「している、いっている、きている」 **+はる**
(*also pronounced しとおる、いうとおる、きとおる)

〖した〗(did):
「した、言うた、きた」 <-- 「した、いった、きた」
「しよった、いいよった、きよった*」 <-- 「した、いった、きた」 **+おる/よる**
「しはった、いわはった、きはった」 <-- 「した、いった、きた」 **+はる**
(*also pronounced しおった、いいおった、きおった)

〖していた〗(was doing):
「してた、言うてた、きてた」 <-- 「していた、いっていた、きていた」
「しとった、いうとった、きとった*」 <-- 「していた、いっていた、きていた」 **+おる/よる**
「したはった、いうたはった、きたはった」 <-- 「していた、いっていた、きていた」 **+はる**
(*also pronounced しとおった、いうとおった、きとおった)

「～はる」 is mildly honorific. 「～おる/よる」 is mild やがる; it's like the opposite to 「～はる」. I think はる is more used in Kyoto, and おる/よる is more used by men in Kyoto and by both men and women in Osaka.

---

For example:

> あいつ、明日、[来]{く}る？
>   -> あいつ、明日、来る？ / [来]{き}よる？ (来おる？)
>
> あいつ、今日、来てる？
>   -> あいつ、今日、来てる？ / 来とる？ (来とおる？)
>
> あいつ、昨日、来た？
>   -> あいつ、昨日、来た？ / 来よった？ (来おった？)
>
> あいつ、昨日、来てた？
>   -> あいつ、昨日、来てた？ / 来とった？ (来とおった？)

---

(Although I am not sure if this answers your question:)

For "The bus is coming", I'd say:

> バス(が)[来]{く}る(で), バス[来]{く}んで, バス[来]{き}**よる**(で) or バス[来]{き}**よん**で etc.

For "The bus has already arrived", I'd say:

> バス(が)[来]{き}てる(で), バス[来]{き}てんで, バス[来]{き}**とる**(で), バス[来]{き}**とん**で etc.

For "When I got up this morning and opened the window, it was raining. (still raining)", I'd say:

> 今朝起きて窓開けたら、雨降ってた。 or 雨降っ**とっ**た。etc.

For "When I got up this morning and opened the window, I found it had rained. (already stopped.)", I'd say:

> 今朝起きて窓開けたら、雨降った[後]{あと}やった。 or 雨降り終わっ**とっ**た。etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Really? So 標準語のする＝関西弁のしよる? もう行くよ＝もう行きよるで・もういっきょるで? That doesn't sound right. I think both しよる and しとる must correspond to して（い）る, no? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @dainichi そうですね、京都・大阪あたりでは、「しよる」は『「する」+弱い「やがる」』みたいな感じで、progressive的な「している」っていう意味では使わないですね・・