# what does 抱えこんどります mean in this sentence?

Tags: words

> すべてを自分で**抱えこんどりました**。誰かに助けてもらおうと考える余裕さえなかったんです

is 抱えこんどりました a rare form of 抱え込む?

Comment: I would guess this どり is a contraction of でおり.

Answer (score 1):

It's an informal contraction of 抱え込んでおりました. See [this chart](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010).

In standard Japanese as spoken around Tokyo, -ておる is basically a humble expression used in formal contexts, so it is usually not contracted to -とる. However, in western dialects, -ておる is commonly used in place of -ている, making -とる fairly commonplace in informal situations. For example, "I'm watchin' it" would not be 見てる but rather 見とる in many western Japanese dialects.

See also:

- [Existence verbs in the Kansai Dialect](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61178/5010)
- [おる in honorific contexts](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26091/5010)
- [What is the non-slurred version for 叫んどんねん? 叫んでおらない?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/90408/5010)