# Help understanding (連用形+) よる

Tags: grammar

「せやけどもう、こんな遠方のちまい拠点、労力使って潰さんでも、勝手にくたばり**よる**でしょ」

Hi. How should I understand  (連用形+) よる? Is the 〜よる same as 〜している?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28277/9831

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be 大阪弁 according to [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%88%E3%82%8B). It means

```
る、ている、
ようとしている、
ている最中
----
る
やがる
```

This is the explanation of the etymology + usage:

> 「おる」の転。動詞の連用形に付いて、動作が進行中であること。第三者の行為や状態の表現。三人称の動詞全てにつけることができ、人間以外にも使われる。。。。「はる」や「やる」とは異なり、「～てよる」とは使わない。「～てよる」に代用される語は「とる」

My translation:

> It is derived from おる. It attaches to a verb's 連用形 and means in the middle of an action. It is used to describe the actions and states of the third person. It can be attached to any verb involving the third person and can also be used with non-humans.... It differs from はる and やる in that ～てよる is not used. とる is used instead of ~てよる

Part2:

> 上項「よる」の転意。軽く卑しめる意味だが、親愛感情を含む場合もある。

> Meaning derived from the よる in the previous paragraph. It has some mild contempt in meaning, but it can also shows affection.