# I notice after the Te form verb there is usually a います or きます. Is every masu verb be able to follow a Te form?

Tags: grammar

> 夕方になって少し雲が出てきました。

what is the grammar point of this？

Answer (score 2):

No. There are only a little over a dozen verbs that work this way.

います, きます, みます, あげます and so on, after a te-form, are called **subsidiary verbs**. They add a certain meaning to the first verb. For example:

- 食べます + います = 食べています = "is eating" or "has (already) eaten"
- 食べます + みます = 食べてみます = "to try eating"

See: [What is a subsidiary verb?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18952/5010)

There are many related questions about (-て)いる and (-て)くる on this site, including:

- [Does Vて+いる always mean an action already completed?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3262/5010)
- [Difference between -ていく and -てくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/5010)

But since every subsidiary verb is an important topic, your textbook (if you have one) certainly has an explanation for each of them, so I recommend reading them first.